# How to obtain the polymorphic relationship of a model, return null Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a users table that contains username and password access data, but this table tries to convert a polymorphic relationship, since the access can belong to different models model1, model2, etc.

**migration table users**

```
$table->unsignedInteger('roleable_id');
$table->string('roleable_type');
```

Model **User**

```
public function roleable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return  $this->roleable->attributes['lastname'] . ' ' .
            $this->roleable->attributes['name'];
}
```

Others Models

```
public function rol()
{
    return $this->morphOne(App\User::class,'roleable');
}
```

What I try is to access the model data through the user, but I always return error,

> Trying to get property 'attributes' of non-object (View:

What am I doing wrong or is the approach wrong?

**View**

```
{{ auth()->user()->full_name }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is no role set for the user model. Check the database and make sure that roleable_id and roleable_type have values in those.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting suggests that the user isn't associated yet with a `roleable` model.